# What is the difference betwen Outlook and Hotmail account?

Tags: outlook

When should one use Outlook, and when Hotmail? Is there any significant difference for live.com accounts?

As it seems, live.com accounts can be set either by using Outlook or Hotmail choice in WP. I didn't notice any visible difference between these two settings, so wonder if I'm missing something?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that in Windows Phone 8.1 the Hotmail option has been removed. The Outlook option has been split into two - Exchange and Outlook.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the crux of what you want to know is:

> When should one use Outlook, and when Hotmail?

If your primary concern is getting your web `hotmail.com` or `outlook.com` email account synced, then you can choose either. [Hotmail.com has been upgraded and re-branded to Outlook.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook.com).

However, the brand name `Outlook` is more than just the web client `outlook.com`.

[From the Wikipedia page about Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook):

> It can be used as a stand-alone application, or can work with Microsoft Exchange Server and Microsoft SharePoint Server for multiple users in an organization, such as shared mailboxes and calendars, Exchange public folders, SharePoint lists, and meeting schedules. There are third-party add-on applications that integrate Outlook with devices such as BlackBerry mobile phones and with other software such as Office and Skype internet communication.

In other words, if you need to sync with Office 365 or MS exchange, you should pick Outlook as the account to add.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.com is Micorosofts new online mail service.  Hotmail was a service Microsoft bought in the 90s and, while still very popular, is getting a bit long in the tooth.

Microsoft migrated all their Hotmail users to Outlook.com in 2013.  so, you should be able to use your hotmail name and password in outlook.com:

John.smith@hotmail.com becomes John.smith@Outlook.com

Comment: As it seems, live.com accounts can be set either by using Outlook or Hotmail choice in WP. I didn't notice any visible difference between these two settings, so wonder if I'm missing something?

Comment: From something I posted on Android http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26850/how-can-i-set-up-a-new-outlook-com-account-using-a-hotmail-account/ , I *think* if you select an Outlook account it will use different server settings and also supports Exchange ActiveSync

Comment: Also, "John.smith@hotmail.com becomes John.smith@Outlook.com" is not correct. You still have to login with your hotmail details unless you manually migrate.

Comment: @row1 I've setup live acc as `Hotmail` and it does sync contacts, calendar, etc. but under account options there is only email sync checkbox (unlike `Outlook` which shows more options to sync)